# Using values from first query to perform a second query

Tags: sql, postgresql

My first query returns the thread_id(s) where is_root = true

```
SELECT thread_id 
FROM messages 
WHERE recipient_id = '331e1bce-2f71-4187-8ce2-edcc615de55b`
AND is_root = true
```

How would I use a JOIN on each returned thread_id to get the latest message?

My second query gets the latest message

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE thread_id = '1b290bac-e694-40c4-86b6-c5b6e09ae8c3'
ORDER BY date_posted DESC LIMIT 1
```

I tried using a subquery but it gave me this error:

```
WITH rootcomments as(
    SELECT thread_id 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE recipient_id = '331e1bce-2f71-4187-8ce2-edcc615de55b'
    AND is_root = true
), latestmessages as(
    SELECT * FROM messages WHERE thread_id = rootcomments.thread_id
    ORDER BY date_posted DESC LIMIT 1
)SELECT * FROM latestmessages
```

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "rootcomments"
```

How could I do this with a join instead?

**Edit1:** _______________________________________________________________

[image]

Should be returning message_id 3 because it has the highest value timestamp

But its only returning 2

[image]

Tried changing DESC to ASC but that didnt work lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `JOIN`.  Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (thread_id) m.*
FROM messages m 
WHERE m.recipient_id = '331e1bce-2f71-4187-8ce2-edcc615de55b` AND
      m.is_root = true
ORDER BY thread_id, date_posted DESC;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a handy Postgres extension.  It returns one row per combination of values in the parentheses.  The particular row is determined by the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: So after some testing I'm not really sure how to fix the current issue. Right now it's returning me message_id 2 and 16 (in edit above) But I need message_id 3 and 16 because 3 is the latest value in that thread. I think the issue has to do with m.is_root? Because in my two seperate queries I would first get all the messages with is_root = true and then in my second query I would not have that is_true constraint, I would just get the max value of date_posted for the thread_id

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES . . . The `is_root` comes from your query.  You don't fully explain the logic, so that is all I have to go by.  Perhaps you don't actually want it.